# What class will be used to create SOAP?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need a class for easy formation of such structures

```
str += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n";
str += "<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n";
str += "<S:Header/>\r\n";
str += "<S:Body>\r\n";
str += "\t<ns2:get_version xmlns:ns2=\"http://gdfgd/\" />\n\r";
str += "</S:Body>\r\n";
str += "</S:Envelope>";
```

Comment: Why do you need to create SOAP messages? Why not let WCF do that for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework has a [SoapFormatter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to serialize objects for you.  Mark a class with the [Serializable] attribute, open a file stream and create a SoapFormatter, and you're good to go.

You might want to consider using XML as a way to serialize objects in a cross-platform manner.  It's extremely similar to SOAP serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` class from WCF, it defines primarily a SOAP message.